# Generate list of floats where each number is inferior to the number of another list of floats

Tags: python, list, numpy, random

I am using the following code to get a random list of floats:

```
random_A = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=(50,))
```

So I get a list of 50 floats

```
[0.35664866 4.76750599 2.05083389 9.53811567 5.36920383 8.91679955
 2.19965617 2.62523134 6.55224616 9.35766331 5.79652488 4.23194067
 2.72168337 5.31431884 8.3975979  9.29497168 5.42797236 5.64302212
 2.91821098 5.06305922 1.88212402 0.24593891 9.45021432 0.95423611
 9.36860165 2.46100709 3.80709829 1.08442665 3.28513088 9.75743916
 5.36187267 4.61001088 0.17912406 6.52406152 3.26927165 4.40187936
 6.79600876 8.10418648 1.06927133 5.3087785  1.85829928 2.20111922
 1.6910625  6.25714944 0.29338196 5.73195802 0.73971446 3.62506435
 9.0166149  3.90316395]
```

What I would like to get now is another list of 50 floats let us call it random_B where each float of that list is inferior to the number compared in the first list (random_A). Could you please help me?

Regards

Comment: Do you mean, say, "for each float element in `random_A` there is a corresponding inferior float at the same index in `random_B`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one indirect way to do it: Generate the first array and then use the individual element of that array as the upper limit for generating the second array again using `np.random.uniform`

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(121)

random_A = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=(10,))
print (random_A)
# [1.11330828 2.10767575 2.32962488 1.51944557 8.30178138 4.07919415 5.557906   7.45523942 2.48499756 9.68659399]

random_B = np.array([np.random.uniform(0, i) for i in random_A])
print (random_B)
# [1.06063118 1.03244254 0.04262587 1.30308582 3.36170915 2.53919206 1.64164697 6.93030501 1.00795353 5.49521109]
```

**EDIT**

Even better as suggested by @Severin in the comments below

```
random_B = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=random_A, size=(10,))
```

Comment: It is slow, don't use loops - just `random_B = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=random_A, size=(10,))`

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: Thanks for the nice answer. I have added it to the answer as your suggestion